# Rails: Microservice architecture with dedicated authorization service and app services using Knock (JWT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, microservices

I'm now trying to separate monolithic application into microservices (dedicated rails app's) and wanted to know - is there a solution to move authorization service from each service?

For example, I have 6 different Rails API services with 'knock' gem that have user model for authentication purpose.
All those services sharing one user database.

I want to implement dedicated service with user model, but how other services will verify users with given tokens?

Also I want to able to control what services user can and can't use. So there should be AccessRole service?

Draft case:

1. User go to 'articles' (frontend UI client)
2. auth_service is validating token from client
3. access_service got message from auth_service somehow and validating user's role to access 'articles' resource.
4. articles_service send response to client with json data.

Here some more questions:

1. How access_service will communicate with auth_service? Should they use one user database to verify user's credentials and role?
2. articles_service and so on - should they become private services without access to public and act as black boxes to user?

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with this problem and there are not any good documented solutions out there.  What I would do is build a service which managers the Users and your Access Control List (ACL).

1. Identity Service - This is where the client will authorize itself for access to the other services in the API.

`login [POST]
email
password`

This will return a JWT token that in the payload section will have the following information:

1. User Id
2. ACL

The ACL could be an array of the allowed roles they have.  This way when the client makes a request to the API the service responding to the request can introspect on the User ID (Knock - current_user) and then you can get the ACL from the payload.  Very easy I think to then add a `before_action` to verify the appropriate role.